# Alternatives to console.log?

Tags: javascript, console

I was wondering if there are any alternatives to writing something to the console without using console messages. My project removes all console statements before finalizing the build, but in a unique case I need to find a way to display something to the user via the console. Is this even possible without console statements?

Comment: No, you can only display something on the console using the `console` object.

Comment: Rather find a way to fix your build process :-) Maybe your removal tool could even be circumvented by something simple as `var displayToConsole = console && console.log ? console.log.bind(console) : function(){};` and `displayToConsole(…)`

Comment: If your project removes only invocations of console methods but not references to `console` object, you can define alias and use instead of `console`: `var alias = console; ... alias.log(...);`

Comment: `const log = message => eval('console.log(message)')`

Answer (score 17):

You can write to console only through Console object.
The Console object provides access to the browser's debugging console.

```
console.log("Failed to open the specified link")
```

You can use other methods for debugging:
info()

```
console.info('Debug message');
```

warn()

```
console.warn('Debug message');
```

error()

```
console.error('Debug error message')
```

time()

```
console.time(label);
```

table()

```
console.table(["apples", "oranges", "bananas"]);
```

trace()

```
console.trace();
```

As for me, I like using console.table() and console.group()

Additional info on the MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console and on the article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-the-most-out-of-the-javascript-console-b57ca9db3e6d

Comment: This question states that all `console` calls are removed by the asker's build process, so none of the above would help them.

Comment: console.info() can be a lifesaver if you are working with webpack etc. and need to debug something before the code is fully compiled, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 8):

If your build process only touches the `console` statements in your project and not dependencies, you can try using one of many third-party logging frameworks.

- [js-logger](https://github.com/jonnyreeves/js-logger)
- [loglevel](https://github.com/pimterry/loglevel)
- [console.log-wrapper](https://github.com/patik/console.log-wrapper)

It is important to note that internally they still call `console`, and if your build process strips out code of third-party dependencies then I must say that your process requires some changes.

Answer (score 1):

Better if we have a short-hand - something like just
log("try me")
typing the whole console.log() everytime is a painful exercise.