# How to return the response to console

Tags: javascript, async-await

below code is showing 'undefined' in console. while the api has data inside it.

```
const getFakePerson = async () => {
  let res = await fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=US&results=1");
  let { results } = res.json();
  console.log(results);
}
getFakePerson();
```

Result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uigA2.png)

Comment: It should be [`await res.json()`](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/#2-fetching-json).

Comment: do `await res.json();` and `await getFakePerson();`

Comment: @Andy Why we need `await` after response got from a request. it is not required.

Comment: Because `res.json()` returns a promise which you need to wait for.

Comment: You actually don't need to `await` the `getFakePerson()` call in this case because you don't care about the return value of the function.

Comment: @Andy Yes you are right.

Comment: Thanks @Andy you are right. we need to wait for the promise.

Comment: here you can see more options other than console.log https://stackoverflow.com/a/49402943/5448891

Answer (score 1):

`res.json()` returns a promise. You need to `await` it.

```js
const getFakePerson = async () => {
  let res = await fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=US&results=1");
  let results = await res.json();
  console.log(results);
}
getFakePerson();
```

Alternately, you can use

```js
res.json().then(data => console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

From discussion and testing the code I knew that we have to add `await` keyword before `res.json()`.

```js
const getFakePerson = async () => {
    let res = await fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=US&results=1");
    let { results } = await res.json();
    console.log(results);
}
getFakePerson();
```

Answer (score 0):

The elephant in the room as pointed out already was that on line 3, there was a missing `await` for the `res.json()` call.

On top of that, I would recommend separating concerns here. Let the `getRandomPerson` return the person and then `console.log` later on in the process. Such as this:

```js
const getFakePerson = async () => {
    let res = await fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=US&results=1");
    let { results: person } = await res.json();

    return person
}

getFakePerson().then(generatedPerson => {
   console.log(generatedPerson)
   // ... do more here ...
});
```

Comment: You don't even need to await the parsed JSON. You can just do `return res.json();` because the returned data is still a promise.

Comment: Semantically that would mean something different then as we are extracting the `results: person` from the JSON object.